# AJAX & PHP = Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I'm reading a .CSV (excel) file using javascript, when I console.out the .CSV data I get it in this format:
http://prntscr.com/ivdn1h

I have to import this data in my database. I use ajax to send the data via POST request to my REST endpoint, where I call the function that does the import.

AJAX CODE:

```
function pushToDatabase(lines){
    var array = lines;
     $.blockUI();
     $.ajax({
          url: "rest/v1/upload",
          method: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
               file: array
          },
          success: function() {
               alert("Data has been uploaded succesfully.");
          }


     });
     $.unblockUI();
}
```

ENDPOINT (flightPHP):

```
Flight::route('POST /upload', function () {
    $file = Flight::request()->data->file;
    $status = Flight::pm()->upload_records($file);
    Flight::json($status);
});
```

But when I send the request, I get this response:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Here is the http request header:

http://prntscr.com/ivdrmz

I'm not interested in changing my max_input_vars. I hope somebody can help me to fix my data format.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `I'm not interested in changing my max_input_vars. I hope somebody can help me to fix my data format.` In that case you should send your data in batches of 1000 lines.

Comment: Could you give some explanation?

Comment: You're going over your variable limit, you're not sending a JSON you're using the JSON to define your input variables (in this case all your post variables). This becomes a very large array. So you either need to split the current array into smaller pieces or encode your array as a JSON string and push that as a string to the server using only 1 post variable.

Comment: Alternatively, don't send the CSV data. Send the file itself, since you can submit files and have PHP read it instead.

Comment: Did the encoding. It works. Somebody give this man a medal.

Answer (score 0):

Check if, changing datatype: "text/plain" in your ajax call, solves your problem.

However, as Niels, suggested in his post, you should actually convert your data to a JSON and then post as single string variable

Answer (score 0):

To summarise, it is the Content-Type sent by header set for JSON. You are trying to send FormData and not Json to php file.

I spent a whole day to discover the solution for a similar issue.